# Filter out posts using custom Post Query

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-list-categories

I am trying to use the categories to make some sort of taxonomy picker. I have a site, which I’m running locally for event planning; I have 6 categories with sub categories within them. For example if someone is looking for a band, they go into the band category and then it displays all the posts within that category.

I want to use the sub categories to narrow the search down so people searching for bands but want classical will find just those posts.  But I want to do it by asking them a question, like “What sort of band are you looking for?” then they select from a drop down of sub categories for the bands. They will do this for each category, make a selection or none so that it gives them a list of only what they are looking for.

Maybe after each selection, it adds that category into an array which is then used for a wp post query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to post it then you can just build your query based on the posted variables

e.g.

```
myql_query("select * from table where catogory = '{$_POST['Cat']}' and subcat = '{$_POST['subcat']}');
```

However if you want it down when they pick it with out refreshing the page then you need to look at AJAX

Comment: Okay. I see what you are saying, what I would do is basically almost like have a form with what are you looking for? which would have the parent categories in and from there load the sub categories based on the parent selection? I will look into the using AJAX for this, preference would be without page refresh.

Comment: The above code is very much asking for a SQL injection attack.

Comment: yes you are right, but if they are drop downs, does that not then make the post restricted to those values available in the drop down menus?

Comment: Well what I want to do is, expand upon it. Where I use the 6 categories I have, and have a question asked for the category. They answer the questions using the choice of sub-categories which almost loads like 6 separate queries but if it could be rolled into one would be great. so it would almost be like the wp query for loading all post by a category. But loading several so.. All posts which are in the bands category and have the sub classical and all venues with the sub manor house etc.